# Scale watermark to fit on different video sizes

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have a watermark.png that was made to overlay videos with 1280 width.
When i use a different size video, the watermark is totally out of proportion.

So i'm looking for a single command that can scale the watermark to fit the **original** video size. I do not want to resize the original video.

This is the current working format i use which works fine with 1280 width videos. (watermark placed left-bottom)

```
-i video.mp4 -vf "movie=watermark.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=1:main_h-overlay_h-1:enable=not(between'(t,30,210)') [out]"
```

On a side note, since the watermark is simply a 15 letter word i could also use text in the command if this would make the solution less complicated.

Comment: What's the resolution of your watermark? And are all videos 16:9?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help!

The watermark = 400x48.
90% of the videos are 16:9 so that could be used as standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `scale2ref` filter, which can resize one input to match a reference input.

Template is

```
-i video.mp4 -filter_complex "movie=watermark.png[watermark];[watermark][0]scale2ref=400*iw/1280:48*iw/1280[wm][v];[wm]setsar=1[logo];[v][logo] overlay=1:main_h-overlay_h-1:enable=not(between'(t,30,210)') [out]"
```

Comment: I'm getting a "Filter overlay has an unconnected output"  error with this code?

Comment: You haven't shown your full command, but you should have a `-map [out]` in there.

Comment: Worked!
`-i in.mp4 -filter_complex "movie=logo.png[watermark];[watermark][0]scale2ref=400*iw/1280:48*iw/1280[wm][v];[wm]setsar=1[logo];[v][logo] overlay=1:main_h-overlay_h-1:enable=not(between'(t,30,210)')" out.mp4`  

  Now trying to get it working with an automated script with the following command (used in a cms)
`$q = "$ffmpeg_path -i \"".$content_path."/".$row['orig_filename']."\" $ffmpeg_command \"$video_path/$subdir".$row['filename']."\""; `

The **$ffmpeg_command** part is added in the cms and executed however here it fails. Can't locate what i'm doing wrong with the script

Comment: What's the $ffmpeg_command string?

Comment: that is the part where i add the command. In this case `-filter_complex "movie=/logo.png[watermark];[watermark][0]scale2ref=400*iw/1280:48*iw/1280[wm][v];[wm]setsar=1[logo];[v][logo] overlay=1:main_h-overlay_h-1:enable=not(between'(t,30,210)')[out]"`

Something goes wrong with scale2ref because when i use the command below (without scale2ref) all works perfectly.
`-vf "movie=logo.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=1:main_h-overlay_h-1:enable=not(between'(t,30,210)') [out]"`

Comment: FFmpeg version?

Comment: ffmpeg version n2.5.7 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
built on Jun  3 2015 10:28:20 with gcc 4.4.7 (GCC) 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)

Comment: You need a version after Aug 16 2015.

Comment: Confirmed working now after update.
Thank you very much.